# Does it make sense to send multiple flags to LayoutParams.addRule() with bitwise OR?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on some code in which a rule is added to a LayoutParams variable in two different ways.  In some of the code, it is done like this:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

and in another section it is done like this:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

In the second section is a comment saying:

```
// We MUST do these rules separately if we don't 
// want to use logic-split for landscape/portrait modes.
```

Does it make a difference, or was this comment the product of superstition?  Which way is preferred, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot use an OR to add several rules. Each rule must be added separately.

Comment: Thanks!  Considering who you are I'm tempted to accept this answer right away, but I like to allow more time for other answers to trickle in.

Comment: I can convince you with the source. The implementation of addRule() does only mRules[verb] = TRUE, and mRules is an array the length of the number of rules. OR'ing verbs will either set the wrong rule or fail with an index out of bounds exception :)